# Why does the typeof return undefined not string

Tags: string, function, undefined, typeof

Why does the typeof return undefined not string

```
myFunction();
function myFunction(){
var address = '12345, Abuja,Nigeria'
}
console.log('the address is' + typeof  address)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable address is not defined within the scope of where you are trying to use it. The variable only exists inside the "myFunction" function. If you move the console.log into the function block it should work as you expect.

Comment: @IkennaOguejiofor You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.